# It is possible to mark domino users contacts/emails/meetings as Normal,Private,Personal,Confidential?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, privacy

It is possible to mark domino users contacts/Emails/Meetings as Normal,Private,Personal,Confidential ? I can only see Mark Private option for contact and meetings(marking personal,confidential options are not available). For messages there is no option called Mark Private, then how can i mark one message as private/confidential/personal? Is there any other flags are there to deal with privacy of the contacts/meetings/emails ?

Comment: There is no such function in default mail database. You'd need to code this (using reader- and author- fields) if you wanted such function.

Comment: @TorstenLink Thank You. I saw mood stamps option in Delivery Option those are consider as private flag ? since they are only changing the icon in email. Whether contact/emails can be mark as a confidential/personal ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want private communication between two Notes uses within the same organization, use encryption. It's there in the Security Options of the Delivery Options dialog. Anything else will be less than truly private.

Also, please direct your Notes client user questions over to the SuperUser site instead of the StackOverflow site. StackOverflow is intended for development questions.  Thanks.